# Matching system using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search-engine, matching

I was looking at [okcupid](http://www.okcupid.com/) and I was wondering ,how I can do a matching system like that using ruby on rails ,I mean

1. members answer some questions and choose preferred answers too
2. matching is calculated between other members
3. ordering members based on matching and enemy scores which is of course will be different from user to user
4. personality matching too bases on the
   questions the user is answering

Do you have any suggestions for a matching systems like that based on answers and geolocation, as I think normal searching solutions like squeel or ransack will not be suitable for something like that.

What about elastic search or sphinx ?

Comment: This question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. It doesn't even involve Rails, you could do what you describe in any language, and any answers we could give would be so high level that there wouldn't be any reference to actual code or a specific language.

Comment: at the end it's database ,matching systems are database queries ,could be done with rails or any language , I didn't find any articles related to that ,that's why I am asking ,as you said it's too board ,but by collecting info from other members ,it will not be too broad